# Is Celery still necessary in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, asynchronous, celery-task

I'm creating a web app with `Django 3.1` and there's lots of `DB interaction`s mostly between three tables. The queries mostly use results that are recent inputs. So `query1` will run and update `table1`, `query2` will use `table1` to update2 `table2` and `query3` will use the `column` updated by `query2` to update other `columns` of `table2`. All these run every time users input or update info.
Perhaps a visual will be clearer.

```
query1 = Model1.objects.filter(...).annotate(...)
query2 = Model2.objects.filter(...).update(A=query1)
query3 = Model2.objects.filter(...).update(B=A*C)
```

I'm beginning to worry about speed between `python` and `PostgreSQL` and can lose data when multiple users start using it same time. I read about `celery` and `Django Asynchronous support`, but it's not clear if I need celery or not.
This is a very simplified version but you get the gist. Can someone help me out here please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would consider using Celery if your Django view has a long running task and you don't want the user to wait for completion or for the application server to time out. If the database updates are quick then you probably do not need it. PostgreSQL is a multi-user database so you do not need to worry too much about users clobbering other users' changes.